# Do US and Filipino cruise passengers need a visa to enter Japan?

Tags: japan, us-citizens, tourist-visas, filipino-citizens

We are taking a 7-night cruise from Taiwan to Japan from June 25-July 2, 2017. We are a family of Filipino and US citizens, and Filipinos with US permanent residence.

Do any of us need a visa to enter Japan? The ship stops in four ports there, Okinawa, Hiroshima, Kochi and Kagoshima?  All stops are less than 24 hours, but we are taking shore excursions.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Timatic, the database used by airlines but also applicable in this case:

[US citizens do **not** need a visa](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=us&DE=jp&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX)

[Filipino citizens **do** need a visa](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=ph&DE=jp&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=us&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX).

Although irrelevant in this case, for immigration purposes your stay in Japan lasts between arrival in Okinawa and departure from Kagoshima. You don't exit Japan when leaving for another Japanese port.